# Importing a Function from another module

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

I want to import a function named `ret()` from a module called `mainprog` into another module named `windw`.

So I did it like this in the `windw` module:

```
from mainprog import ret
```

This is supposed to work right?

But there is an infinite loop in the `mainprog` module.

So, even without calling the function I imported, it just keeps loading forever when I try to run the `windw` module.

So I guess it runs the whole `mainprog` module when I import? I need help to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that the file `mainprog.py` does not have anything besides definitions of functions, constants and a [`__main__` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/10484131).

If you have anything else defined like so:

```
do_something()
def ret():
    ...
```

Be sure to convert it to:

```
def ret():
    ...
if __name == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine, all you need to do is make the loop not execute unless you are running the code by itself What you need to do is add a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
```

This will make your program work as before, but make it possible to import functions within your code